# React Native iOS: telprompt for "911" number displays as "(91)1" on iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, telprompt

Image attached.  When a user clicks a button to prompt a call to "911", the number "911" displays correctly on an Android device, but on an iPhone "911" gets displayed as "(91)1".  How can I fix this?  Code and image below.  Thank you.

```
constants.emergencyNumber = "911";

handleEmergency = () => {
   if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      return Linking.openURL(`telprompt:${constants.emergencyNumber}`);
   }
   return Linking.openURL(`tel:${constants.emergencyNumber}`);
};

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleEmergency}>
     <Text>Emergency Dial Icon Here</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Here is the result on an iPhone when the user clicks on the button to trigger this function:

[image: telprompt for "911" displays as "(91)1" on iPhones]

Comment: What region/locale is set on your phone?

Comment: I tried playing with this issue in: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/telprompt but no luck. I get different format (since I'm living in Finland). But no matter what prefix I used ("-", "+", "()", "0"), it still formats the phone number.

I'm assuming this really requires some Objective-C native bridging in order to prevent "format detection".

Comment: @Paulw11  I believe the region/locale is set to North America / USA.  Would setting it to a different region/locale fix the issue? If so how does one do that?